# Is there a command for checking alias existence in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Is there a PowerShell command that allows you to check to see if an alias exists or not?

*(I have been looking around on the web, and it doesn't look like it.)*

Comment: As pointed out in @Rhumborl's answer, you can append "-force" to a New-Alias command to prevent an error message from being printed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think Get-Alias is what you are looking for.

MS Documentation:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee176839.aspx

Example for IF:

```
$ar = get-alias -name f* 
if($ar.count -lt 1){ do stuff }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ... what about ==> if (get-alias -name list* | Measure | ? -eq 0) { # do work } <=== would that work?

Comment: Don't you have a powershell prompt right there in front of you?

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz, your command using `Measure` looks overkill. `if(!(get-alias -name list*)) { write-output "No alias" }`

Comment: @Duncan, just trying to learn whats possible and whats not, that's all really.

Comment: This approach raises an error if there are no matches and you're using `Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0`(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692(v=wps.620).aspx) . Duncan's answer is a much safer way of testing for the existance of an alias/aliases.

Comment: Why does the example match against "f*" for IF?  Shouldn't it be "if*"?

Comment: @crokusek it doesnt match to "if" in my testing, could you clarify?

Comment: Never mind, I thought "IF" was the name of some alias you were searching for.

Comment: **Note:** Be sure to check if the command is actually an _alias_. In newer versions of powershell `Get-Command help` will show that `help` is actually a function, despite behaving like an alias to `Get-Help`. Functions can be handled with `Test-Path Function:\help`/`Remove-Item Function:\help`

Answer (score 37):

You can use `Test-Path` for this:

```
PS C:\> test-path alias:l*
True
PS C:\> test-path alias:list*
False
```

Just use:

```
if (Test-Path alias:list*) { ... }
```

or

```
if(!(Test-Path alias:list*)) { ... }
```

if you want to do something when the alias doesn't exist.

As others wrote, `Get-Alias` works as well, but `Test-Path` will avoid building the list of aliases so might be every so slightly faster if you care about that.

Further explanation:

Powershell uses path names to access a lot more than just files, so while `C:` prefix lets you access files on drive C, `alias:` lets you access aliases, and other qualifers let you access things like functions, commands, registry keys, security certificates, and so on. So here, `alias:l*` is a wildcard pathname which will match all aliases that begin with the letter `l` in exactly the same way that `C:l*` would match all files beginning with `l` in the root of drive C.

`Test-Path` is a commandlet which tests whether the path refers to an existing object with a True result only if at least one existing object matches that path. So normally you would use it to test whether a file exists but equally you can test for existence of anything that is addressable with a suitable qualifier.

Comment: I prefer this solution. When you test for the existence of an alias and the alias does not exists Test-Path does not display a warning message as Get-Alias cmdlet does ('Get-Alias : This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name '\alias-of-the-command' does not exist.')

Comment: I don't understand anything you said in this answer.

Comment: @Andrew perhaps if you said what it is exactly you don't understand then I could improve the answer? To me it seems that when asked "is there a command for checking alias existence" and I say "you can use `Test-Path` for this" that that is a clear answer but I'm happy to expand on anything which is unclear.

Comment: As I said: "**anything**". What's the colon? Why is `test-path` being used here? What is `alias:l*` or `alias:list*`, and why do they return true or false? Why are you putting that in an if statement? I know a lot of programming languages but PowerShell is its own beast and this answer isn't helping me learn it because it explains nothing.

Comment: @Andrew, I added some further explanation, but I agree Powershell can be confusing at first. It is completely unlike any other shell scripting language, because everything you work with are objects rather than text, but equally it is unlike normal programming languages because it's all about commands and pipelines, and in this case the way that many objects are exposed as though they were part of the filesystem.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. Alias is a PS "drive" that shows up under `Get-PSDrive`, and there are options that show up under `Get-ChildItem alias:l*`, which can simply be tested via. `Test-Path alias:l*`. Knowing about `Get-ChildItem alias:` makes sense of everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use the `Get-Alias` command.

Example:

```
Get-Alias -Name spps;

# If statement example
if (Get-Alias -Name spps) {
    # Do something here
}
```

To get a list of all commands that deal with aliases, use `Get-Command`

```
Get-Command -Name *alias;
```

Comment: How would you use that in an if statement? i.e can you use it with conditional logic? Sort of like if Alias does not exist, go ahead and set one up. That kind of thing.

Comment: The `if` statement is existential by default, so all you have to do is say: `if (<statement>) { ... }`. I updated my example code :)

Comment: Get-Alias throws an error if the specified alias does not exist

Answer (score 3):

There is a provider just for Aliases, and an Alias: location, so you can also use Get-Childitem.

```
Get-Childitem alias:
```

Comment: `alias | ? { $_.resolvedcommand.name -match "get.*alias" }` o.O

Answer (score 2):

(tested in version 5)

Here is how I use the above (Big thanks to all!):

```
If ((Test-Path alias:foo) -eq $false) {New-Alias -name foo -value Get-Foo}
```

This is at the bottom of every script that is or will become a module. It puts an alias on the user's system without throwing an error or overwriting an existing alias if the alias already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you are just wanting to set an alias if it does not already exist is to use the `-Force` parameter in `Set-Alias`, so you do not get an error saying the alias already exists:

```
Set-Alias "foo" MyFooFunction -Force
```

Things like `if(!(Get-Alias -Name foo))` error if the alias does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from answers provided by Duncan and Dana, I have created the following function. i recommend adding it to the file pointed by your PowerShell's $PROFILE variable.

```
function New-AliasSafe {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Name,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Value
    )

    if (!(Test-Path alias:$Name)) {
        New-Alias -Name $Name -Value $Value -Scope Global
        Write-Verbose "Alias $Name created successfully!"
    } else {
        Write-Verbose "Another alias with $Name already exists!"
    }
}
```

Now you can just call this function whenever you want to import an alias.

```
New-AliasSafe -Name wo -Value Write-Output
```

If you want to know whether the alias was successfully created or not, you can call this function like this instead.

```
New-AliasSafe -Name wo -Value Write-Output -Verbose
```

Comment: Parth, let me know if you ever see this as part of any PowerShell productivity tools or profile.ps1 template?

Comment: (Or cross-platform alias/shell/dotfiles template or startup pack.)

Comment: bonus point to read list of aliases from CSV or JSON or YAML

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add yet another way to achieve this..

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$ee = @() # Exception catcher
$Newalias = 'wv'
try{
New-Alias -Name $Newalias -Value Write-Verbose | Out-Null
}
catch{$ee += $_}

if (($ee -ne $null) -and ($ee.CategoryInfo.Category.ToString() -match 'ResourceExists')){Write-Warning "Alias $Newalias already exists";break}
else{Write-Verbose 'Continue on'}
```

Catch the exception and check if *that* matches the condition for the Boolean logic of existence. I've found this works well unless the exception is different than you were expecting.